# Uniting Django Form media

Tags: django, forms, media

I have several Django templates, some with different forms. Some of the forms use custom widgets that need their own JS and CSS resources. These resources are properly specified in each [`form.media`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/)

The correct place I found to put all the media references is in my `<head>` tag, right above my own `css` file. This will allow me to override the look of the custom widgets if I want to. So in my templates I have something like:

```
{% block form_media %}
{{ form1.media }}
{{ form2.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

(some templates have more than one form)

Now, if both form use the same widget, the same JS and CSS files are going to be referenced twice. This *can't* be good. Is there a reasonable way to unite all the media references?

This just *begs* for a custom `{% context_form_media %}` tag, that will render the media of all the forms in the request's context.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a blocks and inheritance.

base.html:

```
<head>
    {% block form_css %}
        {# base css #}
    {% endblock form_css %}
    {# rest of head #}
</head>
{# rest of html #}
```

any form.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block form_css %}
    {# your form css #}
{% endblock form_css %}
{# your form #}
```

That way you can inject only the css/js applicable for that page.  If you also want to include everything upstream for the block you can start it with {{ block.super }}.

Comment: I am a bit surprised to earn downvotes for this.  Can someone explain why?  This is just a standard technique for inheriting blocks.